# Initializing std::pair via std::initializer_list doesn't work while initializing an std::array?

Tags: c++, c++14, std-pair, stdarray, stdinitializerlist

I'd like to initialize a `std::array` of `std::pair` via `std::initializer_list`.

```
pair<int, int> p = {3,4};//ok
array<pair<char,char>, 3> p = { make_pair('{','}'), make_pair('[',']'), make_pair('(',')') };//ok
array<pair<char,char>, 3> p = { {'{','}'}, {'[',']'}, {'(',')'} };//not ok
```

Why doesn't my third option work? Moreover this works fine, as well:

```
vector<pair<char, char>> brackets = { {'{','}'}, {'[',']'}, {'(',')'} };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initializing `std::array` with a braced initializer list is a bit tricky, because you need an extra set of braces (as it is an aggregate):

```
array<pair<char,char>, 3> p = {{ {'{','}'}, {'[',']'}, {'(',')'} }};
                               ^                                 ^
```

`std::vector` is different, because using a braced initializer list will result in the `std::initializer_list` constructor being called, and not using aggregate initialization like `std::array`.